# Using flows to send log messages from interactor to viewmodel

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

My application is written for android in Kotlin. I have a class `CalibrateInteractor`, which has field

```kotlin
    private val _logMessage = MutableStateFlow("")
    val logMessage: StateFlow<String> = _logMessage
```

I am sending messages to the flow by this code:

```kotlin
    private fun log(t: String){
        Log.d("Log", t)
        _logMessage.value = t
    }
```

Then on `CalibrateViewModel` I am collecting messages (and output them):

```kotlin
calibrateInteractor.logMessage.collect {message ->
 Log.d("ViewModel", "Log message: $message")
}
```

The problem is that messages incoming to `CalibrateViewModel` are not the same I sent from `CalibrateInteractor`. Some messages are skipped. When I run the process second time I am getting sometimes messages from the previous run, some messages are duplicated. How properly send messages from `CalibrateInteractor` to `CalibrateViewModel`?

Comment: What does it mean you run the process second time?

Comment: @broot, I think if they backed out of the app and relaunch it, if the state flow was created in a singleton class, it would still be holding the previous value and replay it to the new collector in the new activity.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- StateFlow is not suitable if emitted items must not be missed. If more than one item is emitted while a previous item's processing in the `collect` block isn't done yet, those intermediate items are simply skipped. This is called "conflation" in the Flow documentation.
- Flows of immutable classes like String are not suitable for items that should be processed only once. There could be multiple collectors that receive the items. If you didn't care about items possibly being skipped, you could use SharedFlow with a replay of 0, but then you'd have the same issue in the bullet point above when you transition from one collector to another, as can happen during a configuration change on Android if you are collecting from the UI layer.

To solve these two issues, you can use a SharedFlow with a buffer, and a mutable wrapper class where you can mark items as handled.

```
data class Loggable(val message: String, var isHandled = false)

inline fun Loggable.handle(action: (String: message)-> Unit) {
    if (!isHandled) {
        isHandled = true
        action(message)
    }
}

private val _logMessage = MutableSharedFlow<Loggable>(
        replay = 1, // To avoid drops after configuration changes
        extraBufferCapacity = Channel.UNLIMITED
    )
val logMessage: StateFlow<Loggable> = _logMessage
```

```
private fun log(t: String){
    Log.d("Log", t)
    _logMessage.tryEmit(t)
}
```

```
calibrateInteractor.logMessage.collect { loggable ->
    loggable.handle { message ->
        Log.d("ViewModel", "Log message: $message")
    }
}
```

You might see a suggestion to use Channels for data that should be handled exactly once, but it is susceptible to items being dropped.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What do you think about using old good callbacks for this purpose (as I described in my other answer)?

Comment: I don’t know the bigger picture of what you’re trying to do, so I can’t tell if that’s better suited. It’s not what the original question was about. I guess this was an XY problem…

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use old good callbacks instead of flows.

```kotlin
class CalibrateInteractor(private val context: Context, private val scope: CoroutineScope, private val logger: (String) -> Unit) {
...
    private fun log(t: String){
        Log.d("Log", t)
        logger(t)
    }

class CalibrateViewModel(context: Context) : AndroidViewModel(context.applicationContext as Application){
    private val calibrateInteractor = CalibrateInteractor(context, viewModelScope){message ->
//        Log.d("ViewModel", "Log message: $message")
        logText += "\n$message"
        _logContent.value = logText
    }
```